# How to perform mathematical operations on specific numbers in a string of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

If I input a random number, let's say 1101, how do I multiply the first digit by 8, the second by 4, the third by 2, and the fourth by 1, and add the values together.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you tried? What part of the solution are you getting stuck at?

Comment: So I split 1101 into ['1', '1', '0', '1'] by using list(str(1101)). I want to figure out how to address specific parts of that list, say multiplying the first digit by 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a binary `str` to a number using [`int(str, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

```
>>> int("1101", 2)
13
>>> int(str(1101), 2)
13
>>> int("1000111101010011101", 2)
293533
>>> int("38", 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    int("38", 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '38'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use int('1') to parse '1' to 1

`r = "1101"
sum = int(r[0])*8 + int(r[1])*4 + int(r[2])*2 + int(r[3])*1`